# How to sign in with google on an app under a restricted user on a tablet

Tags: restricted-profiles

We have a tablet for our four year old. We created a restricted user for him to limit his access but are running into an issue. We downloaded Duolingo ABC and I granted access to the restricted user. When we open the app it asks us to sign in with our Google account. This works fine for a non-restricted user, but when we try on his restricted account it errors out. Is there anyway to log into an app via Google from a restricted account on a tablet?